# Template parameter deduction and specialization for functions and operators with different behavior for class objects vs scalars

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I am working on a project that involves some static polymorphism via template metaprogramming. The classes interact via mathematic operations that should recognize both scalar and class object arguments. A basic example of the polymorphism and object-object interaction is:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename CLASS_T>
class BaseClass {};

template<class DATA_T>
class DerivedType1 : public BaseClass< DerivedType1<DATA_T> > {};

template<class DATA_T>
class DerivedType2 : public BaseClass< DerivedType2<DATA_T> > {};

// Operator template for DerivedType - DerivedType multiplications
template<typename CLASS_T1, typename CLASS_T2>
int operator* (BaseClass<CLASS_T1> const& obj1, BaseClass<CLASS_T2> const& obj2)
{
    // Multiplication operation
    return 0; // would actually return an expression template, though this isn't relevant to the current issue
}


// Main script
int main()
{
    DerivedType1<float> obj1;
    DerivedType2<float> obj2;

    int val = obj1*obj2;

    std::cout << val << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This seems to work perfectly well until I attempt to add a template specialization to account for multiplication with a scalar.

```
template<typename CLASS_T, class T>
int operator* (BaseClass<CLASS_T> const& obj, T scalar)
{
    // Multiplication operation
    return 1;
}
```

It seems that this new template specialization is always preferred over the former, even for the `obj1*obj2` interaction, causing the compilation to fail. The scalars must be passed by value to account for literals however the class objects must be passed by reference as they may contain large arrays of data that should not be copied.

What ways could I achieve the desired outcome?

It seems that some kind of template specialization (perhaps using `type_traits` and `is_scalar`) could offer a solution though I am not entirely sure how to execute on this for functions and operators. Other suggestions or insight on template deduction are welcome as well.

Comment: Try using [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to disable the specialization when `T` is not a scalar type.

Comment: Or concepts. like `std::integral`, `std::floating_point` if you have C++20.

Comment: Thanks! @RemyLebeau I am trying to figure out the ```std::enable_if``` syntax. I'll close the question if I can get it working. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @StillUsesFORTRAN for example: `template<typename CLASS_T, class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_scalar<T>::value, bool>::type = true> int operator* (BaseClass<CLASS_T> const& obj, T scalar)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++20 you can put a requirement on your template parameters, like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept Scalar = std::is_scalar_v<T>;

template<typename CLASS_T, Scalar T>
int operator* (BaseClass<CLASS_T> const& obj, T scalar) { ... }
```

---

Alternatively (if you need it in older version of C++) you can implement similar logic with use of `std::enable_if_t` template:

```cpp
template<typename T>
using enable_if_scalar = std::enable_if_t<std::is_scalar_v<T>, bool>;

template<typename CLASS_T, typename T, enable_if_scalar<T> = true>
int operator* (BaseClass<CLASS_T> const& obj, T scalar) { ... }
```

Comment: This answer would be even more useful if you can provide a pre-C++20 solution as well. In any case, why not use `std::is_scalar`?

Comment: This works, thanks! I would also be curious if there is a way to implement this in older C++ standards, which are perhaps more widespread.

Comment: @RemyLebeau somehow missed that it exists, since `<concepts>` doesn't include such semantic out of the box for now. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @StillUsesFORTRAN updated my answer to include implementation for `std::enable_if_t` in older C++ standards

Comment: Just note that `st::enable_if_t` and `std::is_scalar_v` require C++14 and C++17, respectively. For older versions back to C++11, use `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` and `std::is_scalar<...>::value`